# Adding new mimetypes to mongrel from within an initializer script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, initialization, mime-types, mongrel

How can I add new mimetypes to Mongrel from within my app, i.e. from an initialization script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Piece of cake. Adding a few lines in an initializer script (e.g. config/initializers/mime_types.rb) was all that was needed:

```
Mongrel::DirHandler::add_mime_type('.epub', 'application/epub+zip')
Mongrel::DirHandler::add_mime_type('.jad', 'text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor')
```